# need to create wddx packet with complex structure in PHP

Tags: php, wddx

I'm trying to get this structure in PHP.

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'>
<header/>
<data>
    <struct>
        <var name='container_1'>
            <struct>
                <var name='var1'><string>xxxxx</string></var>
                <var name='var2'><string>yyy</string></var>
            </struct>
        </var>
        <var name='container_2'>
            <struct>
                <var name='var3'><string>nnnnn</string></var>
                <var name='var4'><string>zzzzzz</string></var>
            </struct>
        </var>
    </struct>
</data>
```

My code in PHP is

```
$pq = wddx_packet_start("start");
wddx_add_vars($pq, "var1");
wddx_add_vars($pq, "var2");
etc..
$pqend = wddx_packet_end($pq);
```

I can generate the simple structure, but I cannot generate the containers with structure inside.
I've tried to generate a packet, and passing the value of the packet to other packet. No results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can check the following piece of code for your reference:

```
<?php
// example data
$arrBooks = array(array('id'=>1,'title'=>'XXXXXX'),
                  array('id'=>2,'title'=>'YYYYYY'),
                  array('id'=>3,'title'=>'ZZZZZZ')
                  );

// add header
$wddxst = wddx_packet_start('We build a start');

// add some variables
$rowCount   = count($arrBooks);
$fieldCount = 2;

wddx_add_vars($wddxst,'rowCount','fieldCount');

// add complex variable 
$i = 0;
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++){
  $varname = 'book'.$i;
  $$varname = $arrBooks[$i];

  wddx_add_vars($wddxst, $varname);
}

print wddx_packet_end($wddxst);

?>
```